# Should I be offended by my supervisor's behaviour and is this considered hate crime?

Tags: management

I submitted a complaint about an issue I had with my supervisor, met with her, her supervisor and administration & my union rep. I thought it was resolved until I went on vacation and came back to find a black hard plastic rat sitting on my desk. I also have 3 retaliation complaints against this same boss. What can I do? I can’t prove she put it there. Filing complaints is getting nowhere. Could this be considered a hate crime or just another form of harassment?

Comment: what means: you have retaliation complaints against? Does it mean you file complaints against her? in whichh country are you, and what is the work culture around you?

Comment: Putting a toy on a desk is, by itself, not a crime of any sort. And being offended will make nothing better. ... If you have an ongoing bullying/harassment case, document everything etc., but for your own sake don't try to find some drama in every action.

Comment: And while I'm aware that it becomes more and more mainstream, I'd recommend to stop thinking about "hate crimes". Either something is a crime, independent if the cuplirt hates you or not, or it is no crime. Just "Being not liked by someone" is not a crime.

Comment: The common definition of "hate crime" that I'm familiar with is a crime motivated by some form of prejudice.  Sexism, racism, homophobia, etc.   Harrassment in and of itself *can* be considered a hate crime, *if* it's motivated by such concerns, **however** I'm not seeing anything in your question to suggest prejudice is a factor here.  The only motivation I see is retaliation against your initial complaint.  That's not to say it's OK, mind you, but "hate crime" seems a bit strong from the information you've given so far.

Comment: @Steve-O I think we agree that a hate crome needs to be a crime in the first place. That's my point. That disliking/hating someone doesn't turn non-crimes to crimes. Sadly latter thing happens more and more.

Comment: @MaskedMan In any part of the world where it is meant like that.

Comment: Perhaps your best bet is to throw the thing in the bin and let the situation cool down a bit.

Comment: Calling this a "gift" is missing the point to the extent of being abusive to a new user. As someone who apparently knows a hell of a lot better, it's very hard to not see that as deliberate. @MaskedMan

Comment: @Nij Oh, I can assure you it wasn't deliberate. I have some plastic toys like those. Anyway, since apparently everyone seems to think a plastic rat is some kind of a voodoo doll, I have deleted my above comment.

Comment: @Nij Just to be clear on this, I thought the "plastic rat" looked more like this: https://www.dreamstime.com/stock-photo-rat-plastic-dome-cute-domesticated-pet-sticking-his-head-out-house-white-background-image48910266. I usually receive a lot of animal themed gifts because people know I am a big animal lover, it didn't occur to me that there are more "sinister" versions of plastic toy animals. I searched around and found this: https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B008P1ZXS0/refRID=6HMX11RXDBM9GYP8J7ZM Looks like I do know a hell of a lot of things, but there's still a lot to learn. :)

Answer (score 5):

Don't let anybody minimize this. While it's not a 'hate crime', you should be offended and it is probably harassment.

Since you have a union rep, I would absolutely get their opinion on how to handle this. A union rep will know the full history of your complaint, and your situation, better than we do.

My recommendation would be that you treat this like any other form of retaliation. Take it to the people who dealt with your original complaints (and also your union rep). Just tell them what happened and that you think your supervisor did it. I would not expect anything much to happen immediately, but don't let that put you off. Sometimes with cases like this the little things build up until the harasser has dug themselves into a deep enough hole, and then serious action will be taken.

I would not fling accusations like 'hate crime' around. It has a specific definition, and this clearly isn't it. Hate crimes need a specific race, religious or gender motivation for the most part, and unless you've been singled out on those grounds it doesn't fit.

Comment: As per my comment - I would throw the thing in the bin. Ignore it. Let the situation cool down for a while.Give the harasser a little time to  herself out of the hole

Answer (score 2):

You should not be offended. This is the action of a deranged person, who is not worth that you should be offended. Not saying you shouldn't act, quite the opposite, but don't be offended.

It is most likely not a hate crime, first because it is not a crime, second because "hate crime" would only apply if a crime is committed against you because of your gender, your skin colour, your religion, and so on. If the person who did this is just generally a nasty piece of work who could have done that to anyone, then it's not a hate crime. Even if that person hates you.

Filing a complaint *will* eventually get you somewhere. Especially if there is a black plastic rat involved. Arguments between supervisor and subordinate happen. Complaints happen. Retaliation complaints happen. It's not nice when it happens, but it is all normal. But a black plastic rat on your desk, that is not normal. It is worrying. I'd follow DJClayworth's advice, but also mention that this black rat is worrying you. Plant that thought into the HR person's mind, that there is something in the supervisor's behaviour that HR should be worried about.